# Manga about a boy born from royal family with a royal father and hero mother, but abandoned because of a low power level

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Do someone know the title where a child was abandoned by royal parents? The child was abandoned in a forest and the royal family ordered the guards to kill the child but a wolf(?) came and also fought the child, but he was too overpowered as a child, but hungry for milk. Then the wolf became his servant. A human old man came to carry the abandoned child and raised it as his own.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white, and what colour was the boy's hair? Also, you used the [isekai] tag, so was the boy transported from another world?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

***[Am I Actually the Strongest?](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=153516)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> A shut-in is reborn into another world with the promise of a peaceful life. Although born into royalty, because his magic appeared to be weak, his parents abandoned him without a thought in the forest to be devoured by monsters. However, his magic is actually inhumanly strong. Just what will he have to do to attain the peaceful life he so desires?

A Japanese shut-in is reincarnated as the baby boy of a king and queen in another world, and granted immense magical power by a goddess. However, his parents think he's much weaker than he actually is, and viewing him as an embarrassment, decide to abandon him in a forest.

After being left in the forest, he's attacked by a giant wolf, but defends himself with his overpowered magic, and the wolf, fearing for it's life, surrenders. Thinking the boy must be a reincarnation of the Demon Lord, the wolf offers itself as his servant, and transforms into a beastgirl.

Then a middle-aged man comes along, claiming to be a relative of the boy, and stating that he wishes to take custody of him. The beastgirl objects, since she thinks it's her job to take care of the boy, and as a compromise, the man offers to let her assist in the boy's care, as a maid in his household.

[image]

[image]