# Isekai manga where max is born as a baby in a forest?

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read this manga ages ago.

The MC is reborn as a baby abandoned in a forest and gets picked up by and elf and raised in the forest along with some monsters. He then ends up being sent to a dungeon by his elf mother's magic circle. He has siblings all over the world. In a certain chapter his mother purposefully gets kidnapped by bandits/slave traders and he goes to save her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of any of the main characters?

Comment: I vaguely recall someone bringing it up. I think he uses magic to "chew" his food for him until he finds an animal he can nurse with?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50170039-heart-warming-meals-with-mother-fenrir is not the one I remember, but it does have an isekai rebirth as a baby in a forest, albeit picked up by "Mother Fenrir" who it seems sometimes turns into human female.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. It is ***[Maken no Daydreamer](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/demon-fist-daydreamer)***. And it wasn’t an elf, it was a succubus.

> Minato Harukaze died in an accident just before entering university, and was reincarnated in a different world of swords and magic. He grows strong as he is raised by his Succubus mother in the depths of the forest where monsters live. Having the strongest demon "fist" technique instead of either sword or magic, he embarks on an aventure in this new world! A martial arts battle fantasy in another world that begins from reincarnation!!

Comment: Are you the same user who originally posted this question? If you are, we'd appreciate it if you'd merge your new account with the one you used to post the question by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This will enable you to mark this answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) once the question is 48 hours old. Marking an answer as accepted is this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Manga about a boy born from royal family with a royal father and hero mother, but abandoned because of a low power level](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266425/manga-about-a-boy-born-from-royal-family-with-a-royal-father-and-hero-mother-bu), this might be *[Am I Actually the Strongest?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am_I_Actually_the_Strongest%3F)* by  Sai Sumimori. Still trying to confirm the other details, but it has an isekaied protagonist with strong magic in the forest who enlists the aid of some humanoids (a beastgirl and a human as far as I've read) to help raise and support him.

Comment: Sadly it’s not Am I actually the strongest, there is a bit more to the story but it’s a bit weird, when the max is in the forest as a baby he’s about to die don’t remember the reason so the elf(mother) uses magic to return him to an embryo and I guess gives birth to him again?

Comment: @MmAce15 I gather you must've lost access to your previous account, since you used a new account to post this answer. We'd appreciate it if you'd follow the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in order to merge your new account with the previous one. Doing so will enable you to post actual comments in this thread (rather than posting an answer to comment), edit the question without approval from other users, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.